# What is the order of preprocess functions?

Tags: theming

I have started learning Drupal for few months. Now I'm doing some theming.

I would like to know the execution order of preprocess functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The order in which the preprocess functions are called in Drupal 7 is

1. template_preprocess
2. template_preprocess_HOOK
3. MODULE_preprocess
4. MODULE_preprocess_HOOK
5. ENGINE_engine_preprocess
6. ENGINE_engine_preprocess_HOOK
7. THEME_preprocess
8. THEME_preprocess_HOOK
9. template_process
10. template_process_HOOK
11. MODULE_process
12. MODULE_process_HOOK
13. ENGINE_engine_process
14. ENGINE_engine_process_HOOK
15. THEME_process
16. THEME_process_HOOK

Source : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7

Comment: I guess the question is regarding the execution order of preprocess_html, preprocess_page, preprocess_node etc.

Comment: @Bhuvana yes I was expecting that...

Comment: As far as my understanding goes it is 1) hook_preprocess_node 2)hook_preprocess_page and 3)hook_preprocess_html

Comment: @Bhuvana nope, it goes other way around. preprocess_page runs before the preprocess_node.